# Automatically restart django apps on system reboot

Tags: django, pm2

Is there a way to restart django apps automatically on system restart in pm2?

Till now for django apps I found that I have to manually restart django apps.

Comment: what is _pm2_ ?

Comment: How are you serving your apps? Is this development or production?